# Basic JavaScript embedded function explaination

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, mocha.js

I'm trying to learn JavaScript through testing it using JavaScript Koans. I've come across this piece of code I am having trouble really understanding, perhaps someone can educate me?

**Code:**

```
  it("should use lexical scoping to synthesise functions", function () {

    function makeMysteryFunction(makerValue)
    {
      var newFunction = function doMysteriousThing(param)
      {
        return makerValue + param;
      };
      return newFunction;
    }

    var mysteryFunction3 = makeMysteryFunction(3);
    var mysteryFunction5 = makeMysteryFunction(5);

    expect(mysteryFunction3(10) + mysteryFunction5(5)).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
  });
```

So "FILL_ME_IN" must be 23 in order for this test to pass. but can someone explain me why?

Comment: `newFunction` has access to its parent’s scope. Each time you call `makeMysteryFunction`, there’s a new scope and a new function.

Comment: @mosawi one of the timeless resources on learning JavaScript are Crockford's series. It's generally a good idea to mix and match many sources while your learn, and Crockford's approach to talking about JS makes it one of the best introductions to the language.

http://yuiblog.com/crockford/

Closures take a couple of mental iterations before you fully grasp them so hang on and try to read as much as possible on the subject.

Comment: @DavidKaram thanks! I'm downloading volume one now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function returned by `makeMysteryFunction` is an example of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). If you were to rewrite the code like this, it might be more readable:

```
it("should use lexical scoping to synthesise functions", function () {

    // This function takes a number and returns a function
    function getAddingFunction(firstNumber){
        // The function it returns takes a *second* number and returns the sum of both numbers.
        // The function returned is an example of a 'closure' - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures
        // This means it remembers the scope in which it was created and, therefore, the `firstNumber` variable.
        return function addNumbers(secondNumber){
            // The function remembers firstNumber from its creation, and takes secondNumber upon use.
            return firstNumber + secondNumber;
        };
    }

    var addTo3 = getAddingFunction(3); // Returns a function which remembers firstNumber = 3
    var addTo5 = getAddingFunction(5); // Returns a function which remembers firstNumber = 5

    expect(addTo3(10) + addTo5(5)).toBe(FILL_ME_IN);
});
```